# Regular expression to match 3 alphanumeric chars except '000' "001" and '002'

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need an pattern that match any 3 Alpha-numeric characters (like [0-9A-Z]{3}) but excluding 000 001 002

```
AAA - pass
003 - pass
123 - pass
000 - fail
001 - fail
002 - fail
```

UPDATE: sorry for incomplete question. The 3 alphanumerics are actually part of larger pattern: QUEO_BK20\d{2}(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(?!00[012])**[0-9A-Z]{3}**.csv

The patterns like (?!00[012])[0-9A-Z]{3} worked for 3 chars only but not as a part of the whole pattern.

and I am using .NET

Comment: What do you mean by _worked for 3 chars only but not as a port of the whole pattern_? In my opinion it works quite well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your regex engine supports it, use a lookahead assertion:

```
(?!00[012])[0-9A-Z]{3}
```

Comment: Kugeleman. It works when I match only that 3 chars but does not when it part of the larger pattern. I will update my question

Comment: @MichaelD. Get rid of the `^` and `$` anchors (see my update).

Answer (score 1):

You may include a negative lookahead like

```
(?!000|001|002)[0-9A-Z]{3}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest with two patterns:

```
if (/^[0-9A-Z]{3}\z/ && !/^00[0-2]\z/)
```

Or if you want an actual regular expression:

```
[1-9A-Z][0-9A-Z]{2}|0[1-9A-Z][0-9A-Z]|00[3-9A-Z]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all programming logic needs to be in the regex.  You can have your main programming logic do work as well.

Code to do this, in Perl, but you get the idea:

```
if ( $x =~ /^[0-9A-Z]{3}$/ && $x !~ /^00[012]$/ ) {
    # passed...
```

`=~` means "matches" and `!~` means "doesn't match".  I suggest that the intent is far more clear than anything involving negative lookaheads.

Comment: I asked about regex because it have to be in regex. I rarely use regex (otherwise I would probably know the answer by myself)

Comment: Why does it "have to be in regex"?  Where does that requirement come from?

Comment: Does it matter "Where does that requirement come from"? the application is processing files based on file name pattern match. and the patterns are stored in DB.

Comment: I asked because very often here on StackOverflow, people present problems to us with constraints on the solution that turn out to not be constraints at all.